# Join/group multiple topics in Kafka based on identical key

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple topics produces by a external application that share the same keys and they share this model:

Topic1: Produces messages using the unix ms timestamp as key.

Topic2: Reads from Topic1 and produce messages with the same key

Topic3: Reads from Topic2 and produce messages with the same key

.. and so on

My application relies on the final message in Topic3(They're produced within 1-2ms) but I also want the value in Topic1. I've created a class that uses several consumers but I feel like it's not very efficient. How should this be done in c#?

I've heard of the Kafka Streams java API but I've not managed to find anything similar in c#.

Answer (score 1):

[`confluent-kafka-dotnet`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/) client does not support Kafka Streams yet. For more information you can refer to [issue #344](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/344).

However, you can use [`kafka-streams-dotnet`](https://github.com/LGouellec/kafka-streams-dotnet) which is a .NET stream processing library for Apache Kafka.

---

An alternative option is [`ksqldb`](https://ksqldb.io/) that lets you [join](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/tutorials/examples/#joining) streams.